# PHP cURL login doesn't work

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to create a remote login to one website using mine. The users will need to enter their username and password on my site, and if they are registered to my website, their login credentials will be sent to another website and a page will be retrieved.

I am stuck at sending the users' data to the original site. The original site's viewsource is this..

```
<form method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="logon">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" size=30></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password" size=30></td>
</tr>
<td></td>
<td align="left"><input type=submit value="Sign In"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan=2><font size=-1>Don't have an Account ?</font> <a href="?action=newuser"><font size=-1 color="#0000EE">Sign UP Now !</font></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is located at http://www.example.com/index.php

I have tried this code, but not works. This I got from someone who has answered at another question.

```
<?php
$username="username"; 
$password="password"; 
$url="http://www.example.com/index.php"; 

$postdata = "username=".$username."&password=".$password;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
header('Location: track.html'); 
//echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: your url doesn't work

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: I see no cURL in your code, only HTML

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result. This code will relocate the user whatever the outcome is

Comment: what to do with result then?. all i want is just the users are logging in and am taking them to another page on my site via header(); func.

Comment: U should check if the login was succesful before redirecting them?

Comment: hm, so it would be like if($result){header();}, right?

Comment: @DarkBee even after i included a if case, the track.html still loads anyway. any guess why it happens?

Comment: I'm not sure if u understand what curls does. `$result`will be the response of the server. With other words, it will contain HTML, it's your task to detect in that HTML (with a domparser or something) that the user is logged in correctly :)

Comment: but is it necessary at all in the 1st place, i mean my aim is to pass the login data to the other website login form.

Comment: And so u did? The curl post the login data to the provided URL

Comment: i tried echo $result, but no use. how do i send data to that page?. I just need to login to that site.

Comment: @DarkBee, hi i have been trying to solve it for past 20 hours continuously, any help would be appreciated pls?

Comment: These are the things , that i have found out. the other website has index.php, and it submits to itself, the form on index.php on their site, has no action set.

Comment: the other website uses post to get the data, and it uses a cookie to store the login session.

Comment: See this [example](http://www.darkbee.be/cookiejar/curl.php)

Comment: sorry, i do not understand anything out of it. am a noob, just now hearing about curl and all. please suggest me a simple idea.

Comment: @DarkBee, i just do not understand why a simple html form cannot post data just like any other?. i guess , is it something to do with the submit button on the form in my webpage?

Comment: What do u want to achieve in the end? That People submit a username/pass and that this data is submitted in another site and they stay on the 2nd site?

Comment: @DarkBee Precisely, yes, that is what i need. thanks a lot for getting, i was not able to explain that clearly.

Comment: Why dont u Just set the action attribute of the form to the external site Then? This way it will post the data over there

Comment: like form method="post" action ="http://www.othersite/index.php"; ?, i did that already buddy, it doesn't work, can u chat with me now, or send a private msg, am new to form so unable to open chat.

Comment: @DarkBee, Hey thanks for everything , i have found a workaround for this, 
now, this is what happens, if i open the login form page on my website, after submitting data, then the original page's login form appears, but if i open the iframed page of the original site, its logged in. 

What i think is the page gets logged in, i mean the form is submitted, but getting redirected to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

This is unsecure, but it's a way to do it

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
    file_get_contents("http://otherwebsite/page.php?login=".$_POST['username']."&password=".$_POST['password'])
}
?>
```

Comment: where do i paste this?. sorry am new to php.

Comment: Passing the username and password in url, that isn't safe.. :)

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo It's as safe as using POST them. Putting them in the URL doesn't make it less secure.

Comment: @blue112 actually i mean you are passing the parameters in url, they cant be accessed via browser, and if any users logs in like that, the password would b saved into the browser as the url..which will be visible..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo I'm not passing anything in the browser, `file_gets_content` isn't a redirect, it's internal to PHP, and it will do the request itself, from the server.

Comment: Won't work if the server expects a POST as method. This will perform a GET

Comment: I understand that man, that is purely via php via...it is okay if users don't use the url directly..(Y)

Comment: @blue112 btw, the otherwebsite only has index.php, and nothing else. in the same page, the users are able to login, and action?=newuser if clicked takes them to registration page.

Comment: @AlExMeRcER this will work if the other website supports the login via GET request..if it supports POST only, it won't work.

Comment: curl supports only get request?. what if the other website supports  post only?